# Special char in attribute

Tags: python, elementtree

Is it possible to have special characters in subelement attribute names? I'm trying to use a colon:

```
category = ET.SubElement(messagedata, 'catid', xmlns="EE.Schema.SSSS.V1R00", xmlsn:comDef="EE.Schema.V1R00")
```

Which gives me:

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

(I realize now I shouldnt be doing this. I need to understand namespaces...)

Comment: Unless you plan to make your own interpreter, I'd say no. Colons in variable definition are usually used to specify expected type.

Comment: This isn't an ET question; the limitation is caused by Python itself. It doesn't matter that this key-value pair is going to be used to set attribute names for a subelement; the key has to be a valid identifier name *because you are calling a method*.

Comment: It may not be directly an ET question, but the accepted answer requires knowledge about the library, and outside this concrete function's scope it makes no sense. I think it is appropiate to keep the tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Colons aren't valid parts of identifiers in Python, but you can sidestep this by splatting a dict:

```
category = ET.SubElement(
    messagedata,
    "catid",
    **{
        "xmlns": "EE.Schema.VSOP.V1R00",
        "xmlsn:comDef": "EE.Schema.V1R00",
    }
)
```

As an aside, though, if that's supposed to be `xmlns:comDef`, you should not be managing namespace aliases by hand, but by using the namespace mapping features and spelling out namespaced attributes; `"comDef:foo"` with that namespace would be `{EE.Schema.V1R00}foo` and the XML serialization engine would take care of ensuring there are suitable `xmlns:...` attributes somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

**It is not posible without a workaround, nor intended.** Identifiers in Python have to follow the following conventions:

- An identifier must start with a letter or the underscore character
- An identifier cannot start with a number
- An identifier can only contain alpha-numeric characters and underscores (A-z, 0-9, and _ )
- Identifiers are case-sensitive (age, Age and AGE are three different identifiers)

For more information you can check [this site](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/keywords-identifier), where I found the points explained.

Comment: This isn't about variable names, this is about identifiers. Kwargs have to be identifiers, but if you use `**` to splat a dict into kwargs, that's not an issue.

Comment: How does that actually work? I understand that you can bypass the limitations on the name with your method, but you wouldn't be able to declare that identifier in the function declaration anyway (Unless you rely on **kwargs on the function arguments but you would probably be better just using a dict then imo)

Comment: The function OP is describing uses `**kwargs` for convenience; it's a factory function that you can use to easily XML elements into other elements. You could get the same effect by creating the element, adding it to a parent, then modifying the `.attr` dict – but for a convenience function such as this, being able to just use kwargs is worth it.

Comment: Identifiers follow the same naming policies as variable names. I am aware that it can lead to confusion, so I'll change it. Anyway, I will keep this answer because although your answer helps OP using a workaround, it has complementary information about the question for a more general context.